# The rendering result is different from the scene in camera

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I follow Blender Guru's tutorial "[Ways to improve your lighting](https://youtu.be/bum0F00TaKU)" online to learn about the light setting. I use EEVEE to render my picture, but the color in the rendering seems different than the scene in the blender's camera.

What can cause this issue?

The file is below
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure that there are no hiddens object that can affect lighting? I see some hidden plane that is hidden in viewport and not in render, what is it? Is there anything else like this?

Comment: provide your blend file and i will check it out. it's hard to say with just a few infos. And there could be a lot of reasons...but you can also search here for "render different viewport"

Comment: @Chris I have already uploaded the blender file. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Alt + H to reveal a hidden plane - since the plane doesn't have its visibility disabled for render, it obstructs light when rendered but not in viewport when it's hidden.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I found that the invisible plane which obstructs my light.